# Self join many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

From sample data below, assuming Julie (1) has friends Adam, David, John (2, 3, 4).
Adam (2) has friends Julie, David, John (1, 3, 4).

```
ID  Name
1   Julie
2   Adam
3   David
4   John
5   Sam
```

This make a self join and many-to-many relationship within ONE table.

In addition to the above problem, say Julie (1) added Sam (5) as friends, technically and practically speaking, Sam (5) is now friend of Julie (1) as well. This make things more complicated because the relationship is bi-directional.

So I'm wondering:

1. How do I design the database?
2. How do I make a query that will return all friends of every users?

Thank you!

Comment: a self join implies that the table has something to join against itself. your table has no way to do that, other than the obvious "id=id" or "name=name", which are simple/useless joins. this table is just a list of names. it has NOTHING in it that indicates friendships/connections between the names.

Comment: @MarcB exactly the reason I'm asking "how to design such database". (i.e. how to show relationship between each users)

Comment: You need a 2nd table to define the friendships. If a friend of a friend is to count as a friend, that can be derived logically and does not need to be recorded, but you at least need to record direct friendships in a 2nd table.

Comment: @ShWiVeL so in the second table, do I need to record both ways? (i.e. 1 is the friends of 2, and 2 is the friend of 1). I'm thinking of something like:
ID FriendID Relationship
1 2 Friend
2 1 Friend

Comment: It would be easier to query if you record both ways, but it's not required. I'll try to put something together that would allow you to query for it if you, for example, record 1 and 2, but leave out 2 and 1.

Answer (score 11):

Example Data:

```
PEOPLE

PERS_ID     PERS_NAME
1           Julie
2           Adam
3           David
4           John
5           Sam

FRIENDSHIPS

PERS_ID     FRIEND_ID
1           2
1           3
1           4
2           3
2           4
```

Query:

```
select people.pers_id    as person,
       people.pers_name  as person_name,
       peoplef.pers_id   as friend_id,
       peoplef.pers_name as friend_name
  from people
  join friendships
    on people.pers_id = friendships.pers_id
    or people.pers_id = friendships.friend_id
  join people peoplef
    on (peoplef.pers_id = friendships.pers_id and
       peoplef.pers_id <> people.pers_id)
    or (peoplef.pers_id = friendships.friend_id and
       peoplef.pers_id <> people.pers_id)
 order by 2, 4
```

SQL Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97b41/6/0

This will work regardless of whether or not you record both directions on the friendships table.

Answer (score 7):

Pretty much agree with the others. You need a link table. I'll give a bit more detail.. some examples of keys and indexes and the query you wanted (bi-directional).

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.tblUser 
(
    ID int identity(0,1),
    name varchar(20)
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblUser PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

-- Many to many link table with FKs
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblFriend 
(
    ID1 int not null constraint FK_tblUser_ID1 foreign key references dbo.tblUser(ID), 
    ID2 int not null constraint FK_tblUser_ID2 foreign key references dbo.tblUser(ID)
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblFriend PRIMARY KEY (ID1, ID2)
)

-- Add index (So you can get an index seek if using ID2)
CREATE INDEX IX_tblFriend_ID2 ON dbo.tblFriend (ID2)

-- Test data
INSERT INTO dbo.tblUser(name)
VALUES ('Julie'),('Adam'),('David'),('John'),('Sam');

Insert INTO dbo.tblFriend (ID1, ID2) 
values(0, 1),(2, 0)


-- Get bi-directional friend to friend relationships
SELECT U1.Name as 'User1', U2.Name as 'User2' FROM dbo.tblFriend F 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblUser U1 ON U1.ID = F.ID1
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblUser U2 ON U2.ID = F.ID2

UNION

SELECT U2.Name as 'User1', U1.Name as 'User2' FROM dbo.tblFriend F 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblUser U1 ON U1.ID = F.ID1
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblUser U2 ON U2.ID = F.ID2

ORDER BY User1, User2
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach could be that you create second table that stores the person and friend ids. In this scenario, consider the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE User 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20)
    );

CREATE TABLE Friend 
    (
     user_id int , 
     friend_id int      
    );

INSERT INTO User
(name)
VALUES
('Julie'),
('Adam'),
('David'),
('John'),
('Sam');

Insert INTO Friend
(user_id, friend_id)
values(1, 5),
(3, 1);
```

Now the Friend table will store the user_id and his/her friend_id. For getting the list of friends for a particular user, you can search the id matching in either of these two columns. Below are sample queries.

```
-- Get Friends of Julie
select 1 AS user_id, IF(user_id = 1, friend_id, user_id) AS friend_id
FROM Friend
WHERE user_id=1 OR friend_id=1;

-- Get Friends of David
select 3 AS user_id, IF(user_id = 3, friend_id, user_id) AS friend_id
FROM Friend
WHERE user_id=3 OR friend_id=3
```

I hope you get idea with this and can play around.

Answer (score 1):

I tried whatever you written in your query:

```
declare @table table  
(
  id int,
  name varchar(40)
)

insert into @table values
(1,   'Julie'),
(2,   'Adam'),
(3,   'David'),
(4,   'John'),
(5,   'Sam')

select

t1.name ,
t2.name as friend

from @table t1, @table t2 where t1.id <> t2.id
and t1.id in (1,2) and t2.id <> 5
order by t1.id
```